# Show set $\{x\in\Omega : \{x\}\in\mathcal{A}\text{ and } \mu(\{x\})>0\}$ is countable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space.

Prove that the set $\{x\in\Omega : \{x\}\in\mathcal{A}\text{ and } \mu(\{x\})>0\}$ is countable.

I can't figure out where to start. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_i = \{x \in \Omega : \{x\} \in A , \mu\{x\} > \frac 1i\}$, for $i \in \mathbb N$.

Then, the desired set is $\cup_i A_i$ (why?).

Each $A_i$ is countable, in fact has less than $i \times \mu(\Omega)$ elements (why?), therefore the desired set must be countable.

Comment: I came across this while doing research for something I'm working on, and I was just wondering if you could clarify whether  my reasoning for why $A_i$ is countable is correct. My argument goes like this: Assume that it isn't. Then we would have an uncountable number of measures greater than zero, which would mean the measure of the set $\Omega$ is infinity. However, we know it is less than infinity, therefore the sets $A_i$ much each be countable. Is this reasoning sound? I'm unsure whether the jump from uncountable sets to infinity measure is correct.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Good attempt, it is in the right spirit but needs more justification. "uncountable number of measures greater than zero" is a somewhat vague statement, because there is only one measure in question. Maybe you are referring to uncountably many points having infinite measure. Even then, it is not immediately obvious that the measure of $\Omega$ is infinity, because you'd need to justify that the uncountable sum is infinite. Instead, note that if $A_i$ has $k$ elements, then $\mu(\Omega) \geq \mu(A_i) = \sum_{x \in A_i} \mu(\{x\}) \geq |A_i| / i$, so take the $i$ to the other side.

Comment: Thank you for the quick clarification, I had that inequality written down for my more formal proof, so I guess I'm on the right track and will be able to figure it out, then. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @QuaereVerum You are welcome! I am happy I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider the sets $A_\epsilon = \{ x\in\Omega: \{x\} \in A \text{ and} \mu(\{x\}) > \epsilon\}$. Then the set you are considering is a countable union of such sets. It remains to show that $A_\epsilon$ itself is countable. Try using the fact that the space has finite measure.